# does pep 232 also works for instance methods?

Tags: python, function, class, methods, properties

I was getting curious whether [PEP 232](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) (function's attributes) also works for class methods. Finally, I think it does not or am I doing something wrong?

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2014, 12:07:17) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140206 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def a(self):
...             print(self.a.bar)
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a.bar = "bar"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance methods are just wrappers for functions, really. Functions become methods only by virtue of being [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

You can always access the underlying function still:

```
f.a.__func__.bar = 'bar'
```

The `instancemethod.__func__` attribute is the underlying function object.

Once set, the method wrapper proxies the attributes, you just cannot set them directly on the wrapper:

```
>>> f.a.__func__.bar = 'bar'
>>> f.a.bar 
'bar'
>>> f.a()
bar
```

In Python 2, you can also use `instancemethod.im_func`, but for forward compatibility with Python 3 it is recommended you stick with `__func__`.

This is explicitly documented in the [User-defined methods section of the Python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#index-35):

> Methods also support accessing (but not setting) the arbitrary function attributes on the underlying function object.